# c# code efficency

Tags: c#

I have to caculate the number of business days between a given time period which is simple enough, however taking into account public holidays adds in a dimension of complexity.

My solution is not what I would call elegant nor efficient as it retrieves public holidays and puts them in a list, checks to see if a date in the list matches a date within the given time period to be checked by incrementing the date from the start date.

ALthough this works fine I'd rather have a more efficient algorithm has anyone got any tips or recommend a different data strucuture to hold the public holidays?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you've got the public holidays stored in order, in a list, you can just do a binary search to find where in the list the start of your time period falls, and another to find where in the list the end of the time period falls. Then you just need to take the "normal" difference (removing weekends) and subtract the count of items between the results of the binary searches.

Be careful of time periods which start or end on a public holiday!

([`List<T>.BinarySearch`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3f90y839.aspx) method should be fine for you assuming you're using DateTime or some other naturally comparable time structure. Note the return value is negative if the key you're searching for isn't actually in the list (which it won't be most of the time). See the remarks in the docs.)

Answer (score 1):

If you calculate the number of business days between the two dates so

```
TimeSpan t1 = Date1 - Date2;
int totalDays = t1.TotalDays;
```

Then using your two dates, count the number of public holidays in your list which fall between and subtract from the total days.

I would think this would work, unless there are some public holidays in there which span multiple days and then you would have to adjust your selection logic.  Can you paste what you have done so far to get a judge of where you are at and exactly what method you are using pls. :-)

Thanks,

Andrew

Answer (score 0):

Here is how to calculate business days with the ultimate efficiency:

http://alecpojidaev.wordpress.com/2009/10/29/work-days-calculation-with-c/